# Is there a partial exterior derivative?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

The exterior derivative is a map
$\text d:\Omega^k\rightarrow\Omega^{k+1}$. We can divide two differential forms to get the ordinary derivative:

$$\dfrac {\text df}{\text dx}=D_xf.$$

Is there an analogous map for partial derivatives? A map $\partial$ such that

$$\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial x}=\partial_xf?$$

Comment: What are you defining as the "division" of differential forms?

Comment: Let $V$ be an inner product space over a field $F$. Let $v$ and $u$ be lineary dependant vectors in $V$. By definition, this means there exists a scalar $\lambda$ in $F$ such that $v=\lambda u$. Since $V$ is an inner product space, we can define $u^{-1}$ as the unique vector in $V$ such that $<u,u^{-1}>=1$ where <•,•> is the inner product. Since $v=\lambda u$, then $<v,u^{-1}>=<\lambda u,u^{-1}>=\lambda <u,u^{-1}>=\lambda (1)=\lambda$. $df$ and $dx$ are covectors at each point, so they're in some dual space which is also a vector space, $D_xf$ is a scalar at each point so it's like $\lambda$.

Comment: @JG123 that's when we make the equivalence $df=D_xdx$ a property of differential forms.

Comment: Start with the usual exterior derivative and just add an extra variable. Do nothing with it.

Comment: The heat equation is where such things would appear.

Answer (score 3):

Only when you're on a one-dimensional manifold does it make sense to divide two $1$-forms. When you're on $\Bbb R$, in particular, since $T^*_p\Bbb R \cong \Bbb R$, we have $df_p = \lambda dx_p$ for some $\lambda$, and we can write $\dfrac{df}{dx}(p) = \lambda$. You can also look at it this way. Pick any tangent vector $v\in T_p\Bbb R$. Then $\lambda = df_p(v)/dx_p(v)$. Notice that this is independent of $v$, since $df_p(tv)/dx_p(tv) = df_p(v)/dx_p(v)$.

But when you're on a higher-dimensional manifold, it makes no sense to divide $1$-forms. Let's just try $\Bbb R^2$. What would it mean to take 
$$\frac{\omega}{\eta} = \frac{\alpha\, dx+\beta\, dy}{\gamma\, dx +\delta\, dy}?$$
Of course if it happens that $\omega = \lambda\eta$ for some scalar $\lambda$, then, sure, it works like before. What otherwise, what does it mean? We could try takine $\omega(v)/\eta(v)$, but this will change when we change $v$. (E.g., in the example above, if we take $v=e_1$, we get $\alpha/\gamma$, and if we take $v=e_2$, we get $\beta/\delta$.

With regard to your question, $d$ is coordinate-independent, whereas partial derivatives are obviously very dependent on your coordinate system. If you're on $\Bbb R^2$, you might want to rephrase your question in this fashion: Is there an operator $d_1\colon\Omega^0(\Bbb R^2)\to\Omega^1(\Bbb R^2)$ so that $d_1f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$? This is completely coordinate-system dependent, so there's no invariantly-defined notion. (There is such a creature, for example, if we work on $\Bbb C$ and have the operators $\partial = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}dz$ and $\bar\partial = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}d\bar z$, and these are invariantly defined if we make a holomorphic change of coordinates.)

Comment: Out of curiosity does there exist an explanation based on the formal definition of the Grassman Algebra of a vector space V (i.e. using the tensor algebra T(V)?)

Comment: @JG123: I'm not sure what you want. Certainly the only interpretation of $\omega/\eta = \lambda$ (a scalar) is that $\omega = \lambda\eta$ as elements of $\Lambda^*(V)$. If you're trying to define "division" more generally, dividing an element $\omega\in\Lambda^k(V)$ by an element $\eta\in\Lambda^\ell(V)$, then $\omega/\eta=\phi\in\Lambda^{k-\ell}(V)$ should mean that $\omega = \phi\wedge\eta$ (up to sign?), I suppose. Regardless, we need $\omega$ in the ideal generated by $\eta$ in $\Lambda^*(V)$, which is far more specific than what the OP intended, I believe.